# How to made my autoclicker clicks constantly when left mouse is down?

Tags: c++, mouseevent, mouse, key-bindings

I'm a beginner with the programming language named C++ and I start trying to make an autoclicker when my left click is holding down. However, my code still have a problem because the autoclicker just continiously clicks when just one click so I would like to fix that

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int cps;
    system("COLOR 0A");
    cout << "CPS:" << endl;
    cin >> cps;
    cout << "Autoclicker ready." << endl;
    while (true) {
        if(GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) != 0) {
            cout << "debug" << endl;
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        Sleep(1000 / cps);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do anyone have solution ?

Comment: Is it that your click is too slow, slower than (1000 / cps), so while loop is executed multiple times before you even release the left mouse button.